# Set value of MySQL field when displaying data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to clean up some MySQL code another programmer put together so that, whenever the state abbreviation is either QC (for Quebec) or ON (for Ontario), the sortOrder is set to 'ZZZZ.'

The MySQL query is pulling from a table with addresses of businesses, and the state field holds the abbreviation of the state or province, and the state_full field holds the full name of the state or province.

This is how the MySQL query looks at the moment:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    state_full, 
    state as sortOrder, 
    '' as state, 
    state as searchState  
FROM vendorlocator 
WHERE LENGTH(zip) < 6 OR ((LENGTH(zip) > 5) AND LOCATE('-',zip) > 0) 
UNION 
   (SELECT DISTINCT 
    state_full, 
    'ZZZZ', 
    state, 
    state as searchState 
        FROM vendorlocator 
        WHERE LENGTH(zip) > 5 AND LOCATE('-', zip) = 0)
ORDER BY sortOrder, state
```

The way the other programmer set this up looks rather complex and messy, in my opinion..is there an easier way to set the value of sortOrder to 'ZZZZ' for addresses located in Quebec (QC) or Ontario (ON)?

Comment: Where exactly is `QC` and `ON` filter in your `where` clause?

Comment: At the moment, there isn't a filter to check for those, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to include such a check in a MySQL query.

Comment: According to your query, `LENGTH(zip) > 5 AND LOCATE('-', zip) = 0)` is the condition for this stuff. Is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case` expression in the `select` clause and `>=` instead of separate `>` and `=` in the `where` clause:

```
select distinct state_full 
     , state as sortOrder 
     , case when (length(zip) > 5 and locate('-',zip) = 0) then 'ZZZZ' else '' as state
     , state as searchState  
from vendorlocator 
where length(zip) < 6 or ((length(zip) > 5) and locate('-',zip) >= 0)
```

Comment: Ah, okay...this is what I was looking for. Thanks!